# what is the meaning of $|\Sigma|\cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Meas}}\;(X,2),$?

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120942/is-there-a-natural-measurable-structure-on-the-sigma-algebra-of-a-measurable?rq=1) answer to a question on math overflow the following is written:

> If $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space,then one can identify $\Sigma$ with the set of measurable functions
>   $$|\Sigma|\cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Meas}}\;(X,2),$$
>   where $2$ is a two-point space with discrete $\sigma$-algebra.

I can see that there is a bijection between $\Sigma$ and Hom$_{\text{Meas}}(X,2)$ by taking the indicator functions of measurable sets but i don't understand what is the precise meaning of this isomorphism $$|\Sigma|\cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Meas}}\;(X,2),$$ Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Homs are functions such that the pre image of a measurable set is measurable? I.e measurable functions

Comment: Yeah basically the morphisms between objects $X$ and $2$ in the category of Measurable spaces.

Comment: So, doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: So the isomorphism is in the category of sets?

Comment: Yes I would say so, since there is no more structure on either side.

Comment: Well in a sense there is structure on $\text{Hom}_{Meas}(X,2)$, as outlined in the answer you link to. But when the author of that answer wrote your isomorphism, we didn't know that yet. So all he could have meant was a bijection.

Comment: @user2520938 I think its is the similar think like we have in topology :" Any topology $\tau$ is completely determined if we know all continuous maps from $X \to $ Sierpinski space" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathsf{Meas}$ be the category of measurable spaces, whose objects are pairs $(X, \Sigma)$ with $X$ a set and $\Sigma \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. You have two functors from the category $\mathsf{Meas}$ to the category $\mathsf{Set}$ of sets:

- The first functor maps $(X, \Sigma)$ to the set $\Sigma$;
- The second functor maps $(X, \Sigma)$ to the hom-set $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (\mathbf{2}, \mathscr{P}(\mathbf{2}))$, where $\mathbf{2} = \{0,1\}$ is a fixed set with two elements endowed with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra.

Then these two functors are (naturally) isomorphic. The isomorphism is given by:
\begin{align}
\theta_{(X,\Sigma)} : \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (2, \mathscr{P}(2)) & \to \Sigma \\
f & \mapsto f^{-1}(1)
\end{align}

This is easily seen to be an isomorphism, with inverse given by
\begin{align}
\theta_{(X,\Sigma)}^{-1} : \Sigma & \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (2, \mathscr{P}(2)) \\
A & \mapsto 1_A
\end{align}
where $1_A : X \to \mathbf{2}$ is the indicator function of $A \subset X$.

This is a [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) between the two functors, in other words, for all measurable maps $f : (X, \Sigma) \to (X', \Sigma')$, we have a commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X',\Sigma'), (2, \mathscr{P}(2)) @>{f^*}>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (2, \mathscr{P}(2)) \\
@V{\theta_{(X', \Sigma')}}VV @V{\theta_{(X, \Sigma)}}VV \\
\Sigma' @>{f^{-1}(-)}>> \Sigma
\end{CD}$$
where
$$f^* : \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X',\Sigma'), (2, \mathscr{P}(2)) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (2, \mathscr{P}(2))$$
is precomposition by $f$ and $f^{-1}(-) : \Sigma' \to \Sigma$ maps $A \in \Sigma'$ to $f^{-1}(A) \in \Sigma$.

So to conclude: for all $\sigma$-algebras $(X, \Sigma)$, the set $\Sigma$ is in bijection with the set $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Meas}}((X,\Sigma), (2, \mathscr{P}(2))$. Since bijections are the isomorphisms of the category $\mathsf{Set}$, it makes sense to say that they are "isomorphic", keeping in mind that it just means that they're in bijection. But more than that, it's not just a random bijection for each measurable space: this bijection is *natural* with respect to the measurable space.

Comment: Thank you..Since i don't much Category theory so could you please explain what do you mean exactly when you say that "the bijection is natural with respect to the measurable space" ?

Comment: @VictorBarg I've added some details.

Comment: Thank you for giving the details.